# jQuery('#class').keypress Event.keyCode == 13) Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so i have a form with a div submit and want certain inputs on 'enter key' press to submit form.
my html

```
<li>
    <label> <span>Username</span>

        <input placeholder="Please enter your username" name="username" class="login_username loginforminput" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
    </label>
</li>
<li>
    <label> <span>Password</span>

        <input placeholder="Please enter your password" name="password" class="login_password loginforminput" pattern=".{6,}" type="password" tabindex="2" required>
    </label>
</li>
<li>
    <div name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="3">Sign In</div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="gotootherform" id="registerpopup" tabindex="4">Register</div>
</li>
```

And my .js script.

```
////Clicking 'Enter' on Register Form
  jQuery('#loginforminput').keydown(function(event) {
    if (Event.keyCode == 13) {
            RegisterFormSubmit();   
    }
});
```

the function works as assigned it in onclick  for a div so isnt that.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `.loginforminput` != `#loginforminput` and `Event` != `event`

Comment: `event.which` is better than `event.keyCode` when using jQuery as jQuery normalizes which.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive, so you need to change this

```
if (Event.keyCode == 13) {
        RegisterFormSubmit();   
}
```

to this

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        RegisterFormSubmit();   
}
```

Also # selects by id rather than class, use '.' to match classes:

```
 jQuery('.loginforminput')
```

Comment: amended to this still nothing. my bad on id/class was playing around forgot to change back! - Any further ideas? all the code is live, still aint working :/ Nothing in chrome debugger.

Comment: Hmm works in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hxNyq/. (Working in the sense that it complains it can't find `RegisterFormSubmit`).

Comment: Ok Sure, how do i see the 'response' in JSfiddle? Will check it out and see whats up.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by response. The complete page loads in the bottom right corner, then use the browser's developer tools in see any messages. (E.g. right click Inspect Element in Chrome.)

Comment: This was perfect thank you. Managed to get it sorted in the end. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Also you should be using:

`jQuery('.loginforminput')` instead of `jQuery('#loginforminput')`

The # is used for id="" while the . is used for classes

Comment: Thanks this was my mistake, i re-amended the code and missed that out. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You should be assigning the handler to the `<form>` tag. If there isn't one, create one. Also, hitting enter usually submits a form anyway.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  RegisterFormSubmit();
});
```

Comment: Ok thank you, does this require a 'submit' button or will it still work without this? As i have multiple forms could i use $('#formone').on('submit', function(e.... and $('#formtwo').on('submit', function(e... where 'formone' and 'formtwo' are the form id's ?

Comment: Yes. And you should have a submit button anyway for better usability. If the forms should use the same handler then you can assign them a class and use `$('.formClass').on('submit', function(e){})`